# Slice dataframe for each unique pair of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to split a pandas dataframe according to unique pairs taken from two columns, then select the rows relative to that pair and project the remaining columns.

```
df: Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
      1     1     a    100
      1     2     b    200 
      1     2     c    300
      1     2     d    400
      3     4     e    500
      3     4     f    600
```

Then

```
idxs = (...df...) # expression on df
for idx in idxs:
    print(idx)
    group = (...df...) # expression on df
    print(group)
```

Should yield something like

```
(1,1)
Col3  Col4
  a    100

(1,2)
Col3  Col4
  b    200
  c    300
  d    400

(1,3)
Col3  Col4
  e    500
  f    600
```

The selecting and projection part seems easy, but getting the unique pairs doesn't. How can I achieve this reasonably efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `groupby`

```
for x,y in df.groupby(['Col1','Col2']):

    print(x)
    print(y)


(1, 1)
   Col1  Col2 Col3  Col4
0     1     1    a   100
(1, 2)
   Col1  Col2 Col3  Col4
1     1     2    b   200
2     1     2    c   300
3     1     2    d   400
(3, 4)
   Col1  Col2 Col3  Col4
4     3     4    e   500
5     3     4    f   600
```